# NodeJs Mongoose How can I get out a data from "find().then" in a "find().then"?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Sorry for my Title, I don't know what can I put.

Can you help me please, **I would like to print data from a "then" in a "then" ?**

Thank you

```
models.book.find()
  .then( function (content) {
    var i = 0;

    while (content[i]) {
      models.author.findOne({"_id": content[i].author_id}, function(err, data) {
        console.log(data); //here, it' good
        content[i] = data;

        MY_DATA = content;

        return MY_DATA;
      });

      i++;
    };
  })
  .then(function (result) {
    console.log(result); // here I would like to print MY_DATA
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code, and I don't think it's behaving as you're expecting it to.

#### Chaining Promises

In order to effectively chain promises how you're expecting, each promise callback needs to return another promise. Here's an example with yours changed around a bit.

```
var promise = models.book.find().exec(); // This returns a promise
// Let's hook into the promise returned from 
var promise2 = promise.then( function (books) {
  // Let's only get the author for the first book for simplicity sake
  return models.author.findOne({ "_id": books[0].author_id }).exec(); 
});

promise2.then( function (author) {
  // Do something with the author
});
```

In your example, you're not returning anything with your callback (`return MY_DATA` is returning within the `models.author.findOne` callback, so nothing happens), so it's not behaving as you're expecting it to.

#### `model.author.findOne` is asynchronous

`model.author.findOne` is asynchronous, so you can't expect to call it multiple times in the callback without handling them asynchronously.

```
// This code will return an empty array
models.book.find( function (err, books) {
  var i = 0, results = [];

  while (books[i]) {
    models.author.findOne({ "_id": books[i].author_id}, function (err, data) {
      // This will get called long after results is returned
      results.push(data);
    });

    i++;
  };

  return results; // Returns an empty array
});
```

#### Handling multiple promises

Mongoose uses [mpromise](https://github.com/aheckmann/mpromise), and I don't see a method to handle multiple promises together, but here's a way your case could be done.

```
var Promise = require('mpromise');

models.book.find().exec()
  .then( function (books) {
    var i = 0,
        count = 0,
        promise = new Promise(),
        results = [];

    while (books[i]) {
      models.author.findOne({ "_id": books[i].author_id }, function (err, author) {
        results.push(author);
        count++;
        // Keep doing this until you get to the last one
        if (count === books.length) {
          // Fulfill the promise to get to the next then
          return promise.fulfill(results);
        }
        return;
      });
    }

    return promise;
  })
  .then( function (results) {
    // Do something with results
  });
```

I don't know if this will work exactly like it is, but it should give you an idea of what needs to be done.

Comment: Great! If this resolved you're issue, you should vote and accept the answer.